# Can a Many to Many Object be created without a Primary Key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've got Drivers and LicenseCodes in my database where many drivers can have many license codes.

Its also the case that many different geographical regions (States in the US, for example), have multiple driver's license codes so I need identify the region for each license code.

My boss has suggested I set up a joining table that simply lists foreign keys. The POCO model for this class would look something like this (I use virtual properties because I'm lazy):

```
public class CountryLicenseCodes
{
    public virtual LicenseCode LicenseCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; } // This is the State/Province where the license applies.
}
```

This clearly won't work in EF because EF requires the PK value. I'm more than willing to add an `Id` property to this model to satisfy that requirement but is there a way I can do it without one?

Comment: The title asks one thing, the question text a completely different one. How do you expect to identify the correct license code for a specific region without some kind of key? How will you *edit* that entry without a PK?

Comment: Apart from that, EF Core 2.1 added support for query values (later renamed to keyless entity types in 3.0). Before that, you need a primary key, which can be a composite

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so edit the question title so its more appropriate for the question since I couldn't do that right? Other than that, Primary key is essential in EF6 which is fine; I was just wondering if there was an alternative. Please submit an answer then I'll accept.

Comment: probably you can but, you can not update, delete row without Primary key. In relational databases need PK.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a database table without a primary key. It needs a identifier